# How to find nth child nodes in ExtJS 4.1 tree panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Please check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdaXs/107/). I have a node named `Grand Parent`, this node has two child: `Child Node` & `Child Two`.

[image]

When user clicks on Grand Parent node, I want to go down till the last node in the hierarchy and update one of the property in each node.

On click on `Grand Parent` node, I can access `Child Node` & `Child two` node but I cannot find their childs.

What is the way to go down and find every child node in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'cascade'` method for that purpose. (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-cascade)

Like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j27rfzu6/1/

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: "Grand Parent",
        checked: false,
        isSelected: false,
        id: '1',
        children: [{
            text: 'Child Node',
            checked: false,
            IsSelected: false,
            id: '1.1',
            children: [{
                text: "Grand Child One",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.1.1',
            }, {

                text: "Grand Child Two",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.1.2',
            }, {

                text: "Grand Child Three",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.1.3',
            }]
        }, {

            text: 'Child Two',
            checked: false,
            isSelected: false,
            id: '1.2',
            children: [{
                text: "Grand Child Four",
                expanded: true,
                checked: false,
                isSelected: false,
                id: '1.2.1',
            }]
        }]

    }]
}
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
title: 'Example Tree',
width: 200,
height: 450,
store: store,
rootVisible: false,
multiSelect: true,

renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
listeners: {
    itemclick: function (thisGrid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        record.cascade( function(){
            alert(this.get('text'));
        });
        var v = 10;
        alert('clicked');
    }
}
});
```